# Add multiple shape legends in ggplot and overlaying shapes

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create an easily understandable ggplot graph with 3 subgroups delineated by geom_point's 1) **color** (3 colors; for A, B, and C variables), 2) **overall shape** (3 colored shapes with borders; for c, d, and e criteria), and 3) a **cross shape overlaid** over the points (2 groups; some with shape overlaid and some without based on df$Subscale = 1 vs. 0).

I am having difficulty figuring out how to incorporate the aesthetics and a separate legend for no. 3, since that would represent a second shape-based aesthetic.

Here's what I have so far: [image: graph with first 2 subgroups]

It looks okay with with these subgroups (other than the color legend not working yet). Next I want to overlay a shape for all the points with variable names (y-axis) that have underscores in their names using df$Subscale (e.g., A_1, C2_1, B_2 rather than A, C, B2). Since I am already using the shape aesthetic, I don't know how to re-apply a shape conditionally.

Example of the shape I'd like applied: [image: overlay applied to all points when I want it only applied to some]

Here is the code for the sample dataset df:

```
#The way my data is currently structured

a<- c("A", "A_1", "A_2", "A_3", "A2", "A2_1", "A2_2",
              "B", "B_1", "B_2", "B2", "B2_1",
              "C", "C_1", "C_2", "C2", "C2_1")
b<- c(rep(1, times=4),
            rep(2, times = 3),
            rep(1, times = 3),
            rep(2, times = 2),
            rep(1, times = 3),
            rep(2, times = 2))
col<- c(rep(1, times=7),
      rep(2, times = 5),
      rep(3, times = 5))
u <- c(0, rep(1, times=3),
       0, rep(1, times = 2),
       0, rep(1, times = 2),
      0, rep(1, times = 1),
      0, rep(1, times = 2),
      0, rep(1, times=1))
set.seed(12)
c <- round(rnorm(17, .5, 1),2)
d <- round(rnorm(17, .0, .5),2)
e <- round(rnorm(17, -.2, .5),2)

dat<-data.frame(cbind(a, b, col, u, c, d, e))

#Restructuring for graphing

library(reshape)
df <- melt(dat, id.vars = c("a", "b", "col", "u"))
colnames(df) <- c("Name", "Type", "Color", "Subscale", "Criteria", "Value")
df$Value<- as.numeric(as.character(df$Value))
df$Name_order <- factor(df$Name, levels=df$Name[order(df$Value[df$Criteria == "c"])], ordered=TRUE)
```

Here is the code to create the graphs:

```
    palette <- c("#56B4E9",  "#D55E00","#009E73")
   graph_test <- ggplot(df, aes(x=df$Value, y = df$Name_order, 
                      colour = df$Color, shape = df$Criteria)) +
  geom_point(size = 6, aes(#colour=factor(df$Color),
                           fill=factor(df$Color),
                           shape=factor(df$Criteria))) + 
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(21, 24, 22),
                     labels=c("Criteria1", "Criteria2", "Criteria3")) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=palette,
                    labels = "c", "d", "e") +
  scale_color_manual(values=c(rep("black", times = 3)))  +
  labs(fill = "ABC", shape = "Criteria") 

#First graph
graph_test

#Second graph
graph_test + geom_point(size = 5, shape=3)
```

I considered 6 categories for the shape aes, but I would still need to overlay the cross shape conditionally, and I would prefer 3 legends (3 colors, 3 shapes, 2 with overlay vs. not).

```
df$CriteriabySub <- paste0(df$Criteria, df$Subscale)
```

Any ideas/tips for correctly applying the cross shape to some of the points and creating a third legend for it?

Comment: Generally, you can create another `geom_point` argument.  Pass it the same `x` and `y` aesthetics, set the `scale_shape` manually.  You can either use `alpha` for inclusion/exclusion (with `scale_alpha_manual` at 0 and 1), or just pass this new `geom_point` the relevant subset of your data

Comment: Adding the relevant subset gives me the error "Insufficient values in manual scale. 4 needed but only 3 provided." I assume because you can only have a shape aes once?

Comment: I can add a value to scale_shape_manual (e.g., values=c(21,24,22,3) when adding a geom_point with the relevant subset, but it's kind of confusing (in terms of understanding the graph's meaning) to have them all in the same legend. Do you think the third legend is possible?